# Why is generic types from parent class ignoring at child class¿

Tags: java, generics

So, I have current structure, for example:

```
public class Parent<TYPE> { 
    private Converter<String, Integer> converter;
    …
    public Converter<String, Integer> getConverter(){…}
}

public class Child extends Parent {// type does not specified
    public void someMethod() {
        //warn, cause return type is Converter
        Converter<String, Integer> converter = super.getConverter();
    }
```

Why is it starts ignore generic fields and methods that directly even do not use parent generic type¿

Upd: why is raw type inheritance impacts unrelated generics¿

Comment: I've seen this before. Because you're using a raw type, the compiler loses track of some unrelated generics. Raw types mess stuff up.

Comment: yep, I understood that raw types is mess, we can’t change it unfortunately. There was my theory that compiler lose type tracking , but it would be nice to see some documentation regarding this, some evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> ...but it would be nice to see some documentation regarding this, some evidence.

Well, here you go: [Java Language Specification Section 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8).

> The supertype of a class may be a raw type. Member accesses for the class are treated as normal, and member accesses for the supertype are treated as for raw types. In the constructor of the class, calls to super are treated as method calls on a raw type.

From this quote we know that your `super.getConverter` call is treated as a call on a raw type, and let's see what happens to the (return) types of methods of a raw type:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type `C` that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to `C`.

Which basically means: the return types of methods of a raw type are also raw types. So no, your code shouldn't actually produce the mentioned error, and should instead issue an unchecked warning, saying that you are trying to assign a raw `Converter` to a parameterised `Converter<String, Integer>`.

Comment: You right, it warns. The compile error was occur by other reason.